# How to obtain part of the url with php

Tags: php, url, get

I am coming up with a way to display user profiles. Right now I am able to insert the user_id into the url when going to a user's profile, but I am unsure of how to get the user_id from the url.

So at the end of the url I have this:

profile?user=41

I just want to be able to get the 41 (please note this number will change per profile) and then set it to a variable.

How would I do this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: This isn't a form. I am not submitting anything.

Comment: Read about $_GET and $_POST..in your case you need to know about $_GET only

Comment: I know about GET.......... I never said I didn't. I wasn't sure about the method used to obtain the piece of information I needed from the url. A simple... Oh, you can do that with the get method would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['user'];
?>
```

all the parameters of the url are stored in the $_GET variable...

Answer (score 0):

```
The parameter that are in your URL can be retrieved with the
```

predefined variable:

```
<?php
    //$userId = $_GET["pramName"];
    $userId = $_GET["user"];
    // or 
    // using the $_REQUEST variable   
?>
```